# how SCTP multistreaming is different from TCP Stream?

Tags: tcp, sctp

SCTP used multiple stream to transfer single file then TCP that i know but one question raised that if SCTP transfer single file in multiple stream that will increase the traffic on that server then TCP because TCP use Single Stream to transfer file ?

I am confuse about above question So, Pls. help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> SCTP used multiple stream to transfer single file

Only if you program it that way. It would be more correct to say that a single SCTP connection can contain multiple streams, unlike TCP which only contains one.

> then TCP

Eh?

> But one question raised that if SCTP transfer single file in multiple stream that will increase the traffic on that server then TCP

No, because the file is still the same length.

> because TCP use Single Stream to transfer file?

The file is the file. It contains a fixed number of bytes. It's the same amount of traffic regardless of how you transfer it, unless you're asking about SCTP and TCP packet overheads, which you haven't stated.

Your question could do with considerable clarification.

Answer (score 0):

[RFC 4960](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4960#page-21) states that a SCTP packet can consist of multiple chunks, and that each payload chunk has a `Stream Identifier` property. This identifier is used to distinguish between different streams.